# How can I re-enable Pac Man mode in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Seems that my Google Maps no longer offers a Pacman option; is there any way for me to re-enable Pac-Man mode on Google Maps?

Answer (score 1):

There was actually an update to the pacman feature. Make sure you're in **full screen** and it should look a lot like this in the bottom left
[image]